# Is there any way that prevent lua from translating 'a.b' to 'a/b' when I require 'a.b'?

Tags: lua, require

For example:

```
require('a.b.c/foo.lua')
```

Lua engine will translate 'a.b.c/...' to 'a/b/c/...' to search file in the pattern list, right?
Will there be any problem when 'a.b.c' are real folder name? If so, how to solve that?

Comment: `require` loads *modules*, not *files*. You cannot have a folder named `a.b.c`.

Comment: Why can't I have a folder named `a.b.c`?

Comment: Because Lua converts  dots to path separators. The error message shows this: `no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/a/b/c/foo/lua.lua'`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to figure out as the title of this question asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such translation is not on the spec, as far as I know. So it *might* work, but it might also not work. It might break on some platforms (i.e. work on Linux and Mac and not on Windows). It might work in one version of Lua and not on the next. So I would not recommend it.

The way to make sure you stay platform-agnostic is using dots everywhere. Also, I would recommend not putting the `.lua` part at the end, `require` does not always resolve that well either:

```
require('a.b.c.foo')
```

Comment: What if 'a.b.c' is a folder containing foo.lua?

Comment: Translating dots to path separators is in the manual: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-package.searchpath.

Comment: @lfree: `require('a.b.c.foo')` will work in that case

Comment: Well, it should. Have you removed the '.lua' part at the end?

Comment: You are right! It really works when I cut the '.lua' suffix off. Many thanks! @_@

Answer (score 2):

If your module is located in a directory that contains `.` as part of its name, pulling it in with `require` will be difficult since there's no way to 'escape' that `.` so the `\` substitution isn't done.

However, it may still be possible to point lua to look in the right place indirectly by playing with the `package.path`:

```
local restorepath = package.path
package.path = "./a.b.c/?.lua"
require 'foo'
package.path = restorepath
```

But I'd recommend that you try to reorg your project directory structure first so it better works with lua's `require`. Otherwise you'll have to do keep doing the above dance with other modules you might have.